# Call a function in a class with an argument

Tags: php, function, class, methods, arguments

I have problems sending an argument with a function / method call, when that function is inside a class.

I do this:

```
echo class_name::function_name('string_arg');
```

which succeeds in reaching the function `function_name` inside the `class_name` class. But the argument `string_arg`, which is a string, is not fetched when the function runs. It is like that function doesn't receive the argument or just doesn't read it.

*For information: This call is made from inside another function within the same class.*

Am I doing something wrong here with this `::` class call method? It is confusing that I can reach the function, but nomatter the argument I still only get the functions default behavior.

Comment: "The [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class." Please post class code, problem must be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rarely see people using class::function_name() for non static method.  Is there a reason why you use it?

Have you try this?

```
<?php echo $this->function_name($str); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on whether the function uses side effects. If this function simply returns a value then there will be no problem, as it doesn't need to interact with the class itself. I think the problem may be that you are attempting to call it as a class method outside the object your working in. When you add the class part to the front of the call  i.e. this bit `class_name::`, your not actually calling the same class as the one in your current object, so it won't affect or use the fields in that object. If you just call `function_name('string')` then it will use the fields of the object your calling it from.